# DNN OutputCache Error

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, outputcache

I'm trying to create a copy of our live DNN (version 8.4.2) on my local as part of an upgrade project. I cannot get to the bottom of the following error. Can anyone throw some light on this?

```
2018-06-20 07:57:31,511 [IT-Dev01][Thread:7][FATAL] DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at DotNetNuke.HttpModules.OutputCaching.OutputCacheModule.OnResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Do you have your local domain url setup in the PortalAlias folder?

Comment: Yes. I had to update the PortalAlias, PortalSettings, HostSettings and WebServers tables to get past it. I would have posted this as an answer to my OP but was unsure exactly which change fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, I made changes to four of the DNN DB tables and I'm not 100% sure which particular change fixed this. The production URL was being used in these tables and I had to change it to dnndev.me:

- HostSettings
- PortalSettings
- PortalAlias
- WebServers

Hopefully this will be of help to anyone experiencing this error. I would also suggest use of the Event Viewer to assist because not all errors show up accurately in the DNN logs.

Comment: I had the same error after moving a site from production to development. Updating only the PortalAlias's table HTTPAlias field with the local URL did the trick. The error went away. The site is running DNN 9.10.01. Thanks, IrishChieftain!